# optimizing query for DB2 - how to cast from bigint to varchar/char?

Tags: db2

I'm trying to optimize this query in DB2. The inner query to select the url keyword take the query from 15 seconds to about 10 minutes. I've tracked down the problem and it appears to be because the comparison 'where urlkeyword = c.catentry_id' is comparing a varchar field (urlkeyword) to a bigint field. If I modify it to compare the varachar to a string value it becomes orders of magnitude faster. My question is:

What's the syntax to cast c.catentry_id from bigint to varchar? (I think  if I can do this it will fix it)

```
 select 
                    xmlelement(NAME "Products",xmlagg(xmlrow(c.field5 as "ExternalId",
                    cd.name as "Name",
                    cg.identifier as "CategoryExternalId",
                    concat('@bv.base.image.url@', cd.thumbnail) as "ImageUrl",


    (select urlkeyword from seourl s
                        inner join seourlkeyword sk
                        on s.seourl_id = sk.seourl_id
                        where urlkeyword = c.catentry_id

) as "ProductPageUrl",              
                    mfpartnumber as "ManufacturerPartNumber",
                    cd.shortdescription as "Description",
                    c.field1 as "BrandExternalId" option row "Product"))) as xml_document

                    from catentry c 
                    inner join catentdesc cd
                    on c.catentry_id = cd.catentry_id and cd.language_id = -1
                    inner join catgpenrel cgp 
                    on c.catentry_id = cgp.catentry_id
                    inner join catgroup cg
                    on cg.catgroup_id = cgp.catgroup_id
                    where cgp.catalog_id in
                   (select catalog_id from catalog where identifier = 'Web_OW Default Web')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this

```
where urlkeyword = CAST(c.catentry_id AS VARCHAR(n))
```

obviously you need to replace `n` withe the length of urlkeyword field.

However I think that the problem concern **indexing** correctly the tables.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks it works although I just casted to char. The table is indexed, but the index scan, for whatever reason was converting the left side (string to number) instead of converting the right side. So casting the right side forces the behaviour. This works, the query is now back to 15 seconds...